# Opening an Outlook Email

Tags: xcode

I am not new in computers; I am a .NET developer, but was presented with this great opportunity to develop in PHP, so I took it. There is a need to open an Outlook/Item (email) form the website; is that even possible? I know there is functionality in CakePHP to send emails but client wants to use their own Outlook application.

Any pointer would be much appreciated! Have a great coding day...

Answer (score 0):

There ist no easy Way in PHP. PHP will be executed on a webserver and not on the client computer.

There ars some ways to solve this, depend on your needs:

You can open the standard mail-client with an HTML-Link like this:
`<a href="mailto:email@example.com?cc=secondemail@example.com, anotheremail@example.com, &bcc=lastemail@example.com&subject=Mail from our Website&body=Some body text here">E-Mail senden</a>`

If this is too rudimentary, you can send an nice formated email via smtp/sendmail to an emailadress.
[cakephp mailer class documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/email.html)

You can also try to connect via IMAP an put mailobjects into the draft-folder. There are some basic PHP functions for this: [PHP IMAP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/de/book.imap.php)

Only in the first case, outlook will open the email in a Window.

Comment: You are correct indeed Rob, there is no way to achieve that. It would have to be via smtp/sendmail channels, but this is government data so the possibilities of using this method are cero (0). Thanks for the prompt response! have a great weekend!